# how to access user recordings in google home

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I want to develop an action for Google Home that can access a user's recording,
I want to know if it's possible in Google Home and if so where can I read and learn about it.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for an Actions developer to get the user's spoken audio. You only are able to get the transcriptions.